# Android App Not Closing Properly When Clicking Back

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-memory

**Post has been edited**

I've programmed an android app as a practice project for learning purposes. I face an issue where when I press on the back button on the main activity after visiting the settings activity and making a change in there (checkbox options), it goes back to the setting activity. If no changes are made in the settings activity, and I go back to the main activity and press back again, it exits fine. If I visit any other activity and then back to the main, press back again it closes fine on one click.

Below you'll see the back button code for both the settings activity and main activity.

user_settings_activity.java (settings activity):

```
// When the back button is pressed, it goes back to the previous screen.
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

User_Options.java (main activity):

```
// When the back button is clicked, the user is asked if they want to close the app window or not.
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Please advise me as to any other code required.

Any help working towards a solution will be appreciated.

Thank you.

**SOLUTION**

First, thank you everyone who stuck with this question offering responses and comments. I appreciate everyone's help. Now after a bit more tinkering, I've finally managed to work out the solution. Code is below.

Settings Activity:

```
// For the go back button.
public void go_back_butt(View v){
    // Goes to main activity.
    Intent main_activity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), User_Options.class);
    main_activity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    main_activity.putExtra("EXIT", true);
    startActivity(main_activity);

    finish();
}
```

And

```
// When the back button is pressed, it goes back to the previous screen.
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Main Activity:

```
// When the back button is clicked, the user is asked if they want to close the app window or not.
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
        finish();
    }

    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

Explanation:

As @chichiangho mentioned, I needed to take an in-depth look at the stack. With my limited knowledge on such matters I did, but managed to figure out that for some reason the settings activity wasn't closing properly as I had originally theorized. So that left me to wonder how I can handle this properly while keeping my saved settings.

Thanks to @kevz and @MFP response, I was able to create a work around. I implemented a "Go Back" button (see code) and used the kill process on main activity to ensure the application "exits" properly. I also passed along an intent from settings activity to main activity to ensure the finish() process takes place.

Thank you all who participated and took the time to post your helpful replies that got me to think more outside of the box and learn new things about android app dev at the same time =).

Comment: I read your short version and, I guess you are not calling finish when passing to the second activity

Comment: @Mohit G: r u starting MainActivity in SettingActivity on BackPress?

Comment: i think this is the same problem as i found in my phone, only during debugging of my app it start twice

Comment: Since you have mentioned it is practice code...rather giving this long description please add the your main activity code in the question. It would be more helpful in understanding your problem and resolving it

Comment: @kevz, yes I'm starting the main_activity when the user presses the back button on the settings_activity. I'm calling finish() after I start the activity however in the settings_activity.

Comment: @ShadowDroid would you like the whole code (about 445 lines) or just the onBackPressed function?

Comment: @Mohit G: Comment the MainActivity starting code lines in SettingActivity and comment MainActivity.this.finish() while starting SettingActivity.

Comment: @ShadowDroid, I've edited my post with some of the code in there now.

Comment: @kevz, could you please clarify what you mean by comment mainactivity starting code lines in setting activity? Do you mean comment out the intent code relating to main activity?

Thanks.

Comment: @Mohit G: U can check my answer and we may continue in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98649/android-app-not-closing-properly-when-clicking-back

Comment: @kevz, unfortunately chat is a no go. I don't have the 20 rep points to post anything on there.

Comment: @Mohit G: check out my answers see if it helps

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your help, I've worked out a solution. Check it out, I've posted it in my original post if you're interested =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try do nothing when you close your SettingActivity.

here is your avtivity stack.

at first: MainActivity

start SettingActivity:MainActivity->SettingActivity

start MainActivity in `onBackPressed()`:MainActivity->SettingActivity->MainActivity

then finish SettingActivity:MainActivity->MainActivity

see,there are two MainActivities,I think this is why your MainActivity will be looks like restart.

Comment: event you do nothing when `onBackPressed()`be called,the activity will finish itself and back to the previous Activity

Comment: That worked wonderfully, however I've encountered a new problem due to that. Now when I click the back button after changing something in the settings. I goes to main activity. But from there when I click the back button on main activity, it goes back to settings activity even though I've not programmed it to.

Comment: @Mohit G: Start ur  settingActivity for results using startActivityForResults().  Then if u make any changes u can simply setResult() and finish() settingActivity.

Comment: try understand your activity stack,when you start a activity,it will add to activitiy stack,and when you finish your activity(by fall `finish()`,`onBackPressed()`,and so on),it will be remove from your activity stack.your current activity will always be the activity on the top of activity stack.  so,make sure your activity stack is right

Comment: @kevz, would you happen to be talking about this change in the main activity? Would you happen to have an example you can share perhaps to make thing more clear? Thanks.

Comment: @chichiangho, I'm accepting yours as the correct answer as it was the most helpful in getting me to think in a different way about this problem. Thank you. Check out the solution I've posted in my original post if you're interested =).

Comment: @MohitG your solution might be work,but as you programed,when you jump to MainActivity,it always a new one.so I suggest you do it this way： when you jump to SettingActivity,call `startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SetttingActivity.class), requestCode);` and back to MainActivity,do this in SettingActivity `@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        setResult(resultCode, data);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }`

Comment: @MohitG  continue the last comment `@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra("your Info", yourInfo);
        setResult(resultCode, data);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }`
and do this in MainActivity to receive your data
    `@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == yourRequestCode && resultCode==yourReaultCode && data!=null){
            String str = data.getStringExtra("your Info");
        }
    }`

Comment: @MohitG try this way,your MainActivity will be still the old one and will not recreate again.

Comment: @chichiangho I shall try your given method and see how it goes. But at the very least original issue is resolved =).

Answer (score 4):

Override the onBackPressed function inside your Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    // Call  finish() function here
    finish();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I've tried your solution however it did not yield any improvements. The result is the same.

Comment: remove this line :  Intent main_activity = new Intent(user_settings_activity.this, User_Options.class);
    startActivity(main_activity); | from user_settings_activity.java

Comment: I've do so. The problem of the reloading main activity has disappeared. However now there is a new one. When I change something in settings activity and go back to main activity. Click back to exit, it goes back to the settings activity instead of exiting the app.

Comment: You should update your question with relevant code, as this is very confusing with respect to what you have asked and the changes you are making. You do understand the last line i mentioned is the one that was restarting the activity since you were calling the startActivity in onBackPressed()

Comment: apologies about that. I've updated the original post along with the code in there.

Comment: Looks like your updated code has something going on when you select the check box, putting up that code would be the next step to let people know whats wrong. Also when you edit your question donot delete relevant data as it maintains the history of what was asked in the first place. Most of the answers were for solving your original question.Since you have a new one either post a new question or edit the same question but leave the rest of the question intact.

Comment: thanks for the tips on editing. I'm new on here so still getting used to everything on here =). By the way, I've worked out a solution that I'll be posting in my original post as an edit. Feel free to look at it should you be interested. Thanks again for all your help, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for exit from the app.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(MainActivity.this);
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried the above code, but it didn't work as the problem still persists.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I've worked out a solution. Check it out, I've posted it in my original post if you're interested =).

Answer (score 1):

Use this ..

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I've worked out a solution. Check it out, I've posted it in my original post if you're interested =).

Answer (score 1):

Starting SettingActivity from MainActivity on button click-

```
btnSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingActivity.class));
        }
});
```

No need to finish() MainActvity after starting SettingActivity.

No need to override onKeyDown() or onBackPressed() in SettingActivity.

No matter wt changes u make in setting activity don't override any of above methods and it'll work fine.

Comment: thanks for your response. I've tried that but that didn't make any change. I've followed @chichiangho advice and resolved the initial issue. But a new one has popped up where if I change anything in the settings activity and go back. If I were to press back to exit, it would take me back to the settings activity. The code for main activity is the same as posted above.

Comment: thanks for your response and all your help. I'll have to try this tomorrow during the day as it is quite late for me now. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks again =).

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I've worked out a solution. Check it out, I've posted it in my original post if you're interested =).